How can I query GCP BigQuery from SSIS?
We have recently transitioned from Teradata EDW to GCP BigQuery and I am modifying an SSIS package to query the data from GCP. My Data Flow is returning 0 rows.
The query runs successfully in the Google console, so I know the data is there.
I have created an ADO.NET connection manager with provider .Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider using a connection string, and the connection tests successfully.

Connection string: Driver={Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery};catalog=Catalog-Name;connect timeout=500000;defaultstringlength=8000;keyfilepath=C:\Users\UserID\FileName.json;oauthmechanism=0

When I click Preview... in the ADO.NET Source Editor, I get 0 rows back, even though there are over 1,000 rows available. I get the same result when executing the Data Flow task.

Do you have the ODBC DSN set up already? Are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit driver? Have you checked the bottom section of this doc? https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/data-warehousing/google-bigquery-and-sql-server-ssis-and-ssrs
